# Not able to update Magento 2 theme,

Tags: magento2, extensions, installation

I'm trying to update my Magento front-end theme from the marketplace. I'm getting PHP version error **(along with some other error)**.

below is the screenshot of the errors I am a getting.

[image]

I checked `phpinfo()`, My server is configured with **PHP 7.0.27**. I hope Magento-2 is compatible with this PHP version. Please help me on this errors.

Comment: Make sure your server and environment are set up correctly.

Comment: @Aasim Goriya, Could you please help me how to check server environment. Is there is any way to do same inside Magento, Sorry I'm very new in Magento :)